# Access to my GridViewItem's UI Element in Windows 8 Apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

In XAML I implemented a GridView binded with data. In the GridViewItem I put a StackPanel with TextBlock etc. and I would like to manipulate the look of the TextBlock (by its attributes) when that specific GridViewItem is clicked. I can't reach the TextBlock from the C# code so I can't reach its attributes either. What am I missing here? Thanks in advance. Here is some XAML code:

```
<GridView x:Name="gw" ...>
   <GridView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <GridViewItem x:Name="gwi">
           <StackPanel>
              <TextBlock x:Name="tb">
                 <Run Text="{Binding SomeData}"/>
              </TextBlock>
           </StackPanel>
        </GridViewItem>
      </DataTemplate>
   </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

In this example, how can I use the "tb" named TextBlock and its attributes? I can use only "gw".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to access each individual element in the data template. You can however, modify the TextBlock's attributes using data binding. You can use a binding converter to convert the values as may be required.

Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx